# How to download csv file from Google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, mysqli, google-cloud-platform

I can't download file from google app engine. This is working in Compute engine.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $table ";

$query = $db->runQuery($sql);

if($query->num_rows > 0) {
    $delimiter = ",";
    $filename = $table . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";  

    // create a file pointer
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

    // set column headers
    $fields = array('id', 'srno', 'empid', 'empname');
    fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);

    // output each row of the data, format line as csv and write to file pointer
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        // $status = ($row['status'] == '1') ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';
        $lineData = array(
            $row['id'], $row['srno'], $row['empid'], $row['empname'], ]
        );
        fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }

    // move back to beginning of file
    fseek($f, 0);

    // set headers to download file rather than display it
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

    //output all remaining data on a file pointer
    fpassthru($f);
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the logs, error message? How did you deploy this app? Can you show the `app.yaml`? Is the App in the same project as the Cloud SQL instance? Standard or Flexible environment? PHP 5 or 7?

Most common issues while connecting App Engine to Cloud SQL:

- App Engine service account must have the Cloud SQL Admin role
- Project in which the Cloud SQL instance resides must have both the Cloud SQL and the SQL Admin API activated
- The connection between the app and the MySQL instance is done via proxy, that you configure in your php code and yaml file.

Here is an example of connection to a MySQL instance from PHP72, you can also use this code for local testing. For this you will need to [install and run the Cloud SQL Proxy Client](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-proxy-test).

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: php72

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: auto

env_variables:
  MYSQL_USER: [MYSQL_USER]
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: [MYSQL_PASSWORD]
  MYSQL_DSN: 'mysql:dbname=[MYSQL_DB_NAME];unix_socket=/cloudsql/[MYSQL_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]'

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: [MYSQL_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $user = getenv('MYSQL_USER');
    $password = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD');
    $dsn = getenv("MYSQL_DSN") ?: "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=[MYSQL_DB_NAME]";

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully"; 
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * from [MYSQL_TABLE_NAME]");
    $statement->execute();
    $all = $statement->fetchAll();

    foreach ($all as $data) {
      echo $data["id"];
    }
?>
```